# How should a good mobile database logic be structured?

Tags: android, oop, android-sqlite

So far I've made dozens of apps which use database. I did not go too deep into database logic and how to structure it, but made it as simple as possible and by the rules.

For example, my database logic usually consists of one database class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Then I make CRUD methods for each table. Each time I have to deal with a database, I make a special `AsyncTask` and within it deal with the database. And this is it.

Talking to some developers, I was told that my logic structure should be more complex, more OOP. I tried finding samples on the net but they all were directed towards explaining how to deal with the database. I even reviewed some open source projects but they had the logic similar to mine.

Can you help me? How should I make database logic more OOP? I guess they mentioned that I should be able to reuse this logic in the future, changing only the lowest part which deals with a specific database and its tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly subjective question, so here's a subjective answer. There is not *one* correct way to do it imho, I can only speak about how I personally like to work (the big project version, for small projects there's another story). For you or your team it might be different.

For the reference, I work mostly agile, e.g. requirements can change. APIs within the code can change (and do that quite often). This - of course - influences what I consider as useful and what I consider as not useful for my personal work.

Also, I like to work without big frameworks, whereever possible. That's why there is no framework in the model explained below.

---

I divide database work into **three parts** to work with: (quite some similatities with the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

- The actual **database backend** (which can execute SQL). Can contain own code for cross-platform work.
- The **storage class(es)**, that takes care of storing application-specific information. Each piece of information can be read and set from storage classes, (example: `interface AddressBook` provides access to elements of the type `interface Contact`, which have getters and setters for some stuff. The implementation translates that to a single table in the backend).
- The **application code**, which performs actual work and is splitted up further depending on the application (example: stuff providing an address book GUI, etc.).

Why do I split that way? Well, one reason is the ease to switch to a new storage or database backend. If I discover that there could be more preformance when restructuring tables so that new requirements can be met, I update the storage classes. That way I do not have to touch any application logic (example: adding a 1:n table for email addresses to the address book. The new table and its relations do not affect any code within the application, it can recive a list of email addresses from a contact, and add or remove them with ease).

One other reason is that the application code is easy to read (as it consists of, well, application code), while storage code is also easy to read (as it only takes care of storing, caching and similar stuff).

The third reason is that in the case I wish to add another storage mechanism (for example when switching to a platform with a built-in database backend or when adding optional web services) - I can use all OOP mechanisms on the three layers; multiple storages for example can coexist within the same application, so that the user could choose between storing data locally (storage with database backend) or in the cloud.

---

I hope this answer gave you a little insight of some possibilities with OOP in database-related parts of your application. Again, this is *not* the one correct way to do it, just one I found working quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Try ORMLite

Object Relational Mapping Lite (ORM Lite) provides some lightweight functionality for persisting Java objects to SQL databases while avoiding the complexity and overhead of more standard ORM packages. It supports a number of SQL databases using JDBC and also supports Sqlite with native calls to Android OS database APIs.

http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

http://sourabhsaldi.blogspot.in/2012/10/ormlite-tutorial.html